# Webklex/laravel-IMAP getHeader() gives object type

Tags: php, laravel, imap

From an inbox mail (from gmail), I need to track a bounced email address. I know that the email address of the failed email (bounced) lies in the Header of the email as

```
X-Failed-Recipients: bouncedemail@example.com
```

But using

```
$result = $oMessage->getHeader();
```

returns an IMAP/Header Object. I printed this using print_r() and got this garbage text:

```
Webklex\PHPIMAP\Header Object ( [raw] => Delivered-To: example@gmail.com Received: by 2002:ac2:5e31:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id o17csp7225643lfg; Thu, 24 Dec 2020 02:20:17 -0800 (PST) X-Received: by 2002:a63:4c09:: with SMTP id z9mr9692975pga.260.1608805216889; Thu, 24 Dec 2020 02:20:16 -0800 (PST) ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1608805216; cv=none; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816; b=AI9TUX1C+wJBqqXwpMaF/uDrXyMgFMwBML2e/YMqabdun7/ul7vY6WWw2fx3uD/nR8 xVqJZ3UtD+ZIchQNsSWhWYZqfuOa/Dj9WZvohqdXOutgecBi6zxLyeG5OIAfy+9NleGz 6xLfiVWo56heKLXBqXeNbNaQ+LXLDvKm6E6i1uiCeYUmM/tw0ZIkQdruRVqP2xGqzXKh xvgl8cljKaG5MDPNmU8v/hc0rHFGKAcJi8J20nPeYdfp10djiXfLU1v9OxV/UayEf5l3 0yPhGW9shprFd+GvB4dgZ+OLtn/R5mjEW+vYeKIthvfs2Dga2O63icmBRweGEHg8yeyX 0kig== ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816; h=in-reply-to:references:subject:from:date:message-id:auto-submitted :to:dkim-signature; bh=HVsNyAXsGd1kVtDekkg2HxIra2/JCXrqUZz681BppKw=; b=hFfcZH0aA/LJbX5isnTOLKGlkUAVzb/qxN0GDBIoeC2eUb0xQDH4RCIOCorS3RP8zk jzJPOmJtz8Vj8+IwFb5yYbJv9piGVXQzBHjhdJhlSrO+oPm+l1yG0wys1a4wqWbqrWAw VDFsmEAJF9+9I4bi0Wtng1ta6hi/Mv+9sBEdPt2RQlDmdqOhVDZEqRJLHxcUgIdFPCVZ 4cU9oQZWu+3V6PU1x7Rdjn11gQFBmWICrO3FTE5Op7wPsMc3vHm1NYFVS8netcE/CQpB kYj/c/rpTrDhwdxiz6phRGFpE5o81ZIfe2p3/z8bWwZG7ILHuZmH3nDD2Fwxrzt9qFls mDZQ== ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com; dkim=pass header.i=@googlemail.com header.s=20161025 header.b=Sz17ewkg; spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of postmaster@mail-sor-f69.google.com designates 209.85.220.69 as permitted sender) smtp.helo=mail-sor-f69.google.com; dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=googlemail.com Return-Path: <> Received: from mail-sor-f69.google.com (mail-sor-f69.google.com. [209.85.220.69]) by mx.google.com with SMTPS id fw10sor1080243pjb.17.2020.12.24.02.20.16 for (Google Transport Security); Thu, 24 Dec 2020 02:20:16 -0800 (PST) Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of postmaster@mail-sor-f69.google.com designates 209.85.220.69 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.220.69; Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; dkim=pass header.i=@googlemail.com header.s=20161025 header.b=Sz17ewkg; spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of postmaster@mail-sor-f69.google.com designates 209.85.220.69 as permitted sender) smtp.helo=mail-sor-f69.google.com; dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=googlemail.com DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=googlemail.com; s=20161025; h=to:auto-submitted:message-id:date:from:subject:references :in-reply-to; bh=HVsNyAXsGd1kVtDekkg2HxIra2/JCXrqUZz681BppKw=; b=Sz17ewkg50XRKx13ZXL+uhs7X0kxjI7llTlUED6DSysnUo0GeLXgvQwRao3AM5hLUr r6TCdSIUIwuLOfdl8hmouMadPdH2gB8a0KF2FYDHffWwYNir1hNLBVTyXvo5LPwykMvP EgqjIC8hNpdG93Dd8Zu0/65iaWGJhBf4Tm3N/f3BRHYV50xkfiov2ahQZwqlvY9wUeco /VWSoJZ66qUTfyn9nrs9arRV52tmMeoggox9ttUy7Iz1w62al6IrxYiDDyWDdgMOXxEw qe4nrEPXGSClSFrbAAySQkRT89iwpc3AEfK8tYcF4JOqd5eKbLCloIjFmdkcrI0wT/W4 c85w== X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=1e100.net; s=20161025; h=x-gm-message-state:to:auto-submitted:message-id:date:from:subject :references:in-reply-to; bh=HVsNyAXsGd1kVtDekkg2HxIra2/JCXrqUZz681BppKw=; b=bAyKPMCTjikcjsyEbB2ibqPegW9t9hHkozBFt6PJfqslJwnt1jpBJOlQbXF6lIIsM8 DWDiaKVQy2sPRLw/TmDFXl1GDhUOrZWAyQ2Q5w4QYscsVMOUVLbuFhlVbl44ymn+Lfzd wtNni3koNftCRnAcCySkt5mqPhZLgagPMX0/afPKAeW9bKCrCrXKjv4cXXCX4ojD1/e9 9M4iC76e1mqy4MOEb8JdYSfXuuQuKh5dHN97kX0H7LisPmMvZxIMlQiI0+2LsEx5eG4k gBRe2RuKDNgeTjbUGaSP+pyU32PZZIcHzhBNxQe6W9RyrgN0pPevYY4cOP9+xKH4f2Ug ggkw== X-Gm-Message-State: AOAM531WciQHOtxqIaSzQO4gea2X9+tWwU/SYEYWxHxzU1sV4LXznlG1 eT9u1p1APRctY02WPSHp9kzxnP82+e2FdOU+JXZ/2g== X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABdhPJzX5IFD/kv3qPD1smc2KPY3k5YnHwKkGPrXRCYiqcETxF4d4O5XCd1SAfrlKi6WHdq714K+XraLZOYvXWSjaz7qacYYDv1bfEc= X-Received: by 2002:a17:90a:f48b:: with SMTP id bx11mr3793822pjb.48.1608805216636; Thu, 24 Dec 2020 02:20:16 -0800 (PST) Content-Type: multipart/report; boundary="00000000000073416e05b73327e3"; report-type=delivery-status To: chamere528@gmail.com Received: by 2002:a17:90a:f48b:: with SMTP id bx11mr3066321pjb.48; Thu, 24 Dec 2020 02:20:16 -0800 (PST) Return-Path: <> Auto-Submitted: auto-replied Message-ID: <5fe46b60.1c69fb81.530ad.4c45.GMR@mx.google.com> Date: Thu, 24 Dec 2020 02:20:16 -0800 (PST) From: Mail Delivery Subsystem Subject: Delivery Status Notification (Failure) References: In-Reply-To: X-Failed-Recipients: gh528@gmail.com [attributes:protected] => Array ( [from] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [personal] => Mail Delivery Subsystem [mailbox] => mailer-daemon [host] => googlemail.com [mail] => mailer-daemon@googlemail.com [full] => Mail Delivery Subsystem ) ) [to] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [mailbox] => chamere528 [host] => gmail.com [personal] => [mail] => chamere528@gmail.com [full] => chamere528@gmail.com ) ) [reply_to] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [personal] => Mail Delivery Subsystem [mailbox] => mailer-daemon [host] => googlemail.com [mail] => mailer-daemon@googlemail.com [full] => Mail Delivery Subsystem ) ) [sender] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [personal] => Mail Delivery Subsystem [mailbox] => mailer-daemon [host] => googlemail.com [mail] => mailer-daemon@googlemail.com [full] => Mail Delivery Subsystem ) ) [subject] => Delivery Status Notification (Failure) [in_reply_to] => Array ( [0] => ) [references] => [message_id] => 5fe46b60.1c69fb81.530ad.4c45.GMR@mx.google.com [date] => Carbon\Carbon Object ( [date] => 2020-12-24 02:20:16.000000 [timezone_type] => 1 [timezone] => -08:00 ) [delivered_to] => chamere528@gmail.com [received] => Array ( [0] => by 2002:ac2:5e31:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id o17csp7225643lfg; Thu, 24 [1] => Dec 2020 02:20:17 -0800 (PST) [2] => from mail-sor-f69.google.com (mail-sor-f69.google.com. [3] => [209.85.220.69]) by mx.google.com with SMTPS id [4] => fw10sor1080243pjb.17.2020.12.24.02.20.16 for (Google [5] => Transport Security); Thu, 24 Dec 2020 02:20:16 -0800 (PST) [6] => by 2002:a17:90a:f48b:: with SMTP id bx11mr3066321pjb.48; Thu, 24 Dec [7] => 2020 02:20:16 -0800 (PST) ) [x_received] => Array ( [0] => by 2002:a63:4c09:: with SMTP id z9mr9692975pga.260.1608805216889; [1] => Thu, 24 Dec 2020 02:20:16 -0800 (PST) [2] => by 2002:a17:90a:f48b:: with SMTP id [3] => bx11mr3793822pjb.48.1608805216636; Thu, 24 Dec 2020 02:20:16 -0800 (PST) ) [arc_seal] => Array ( [0] => i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1608805216; cv=none; d=google.com; [1] => s=arc-20160816; [2] => b=AI9TUX1C+wJBqqXwpMaF/uDrXyMgFMwBML2e/YMqabdun7/ul7vY6WWw2fx3uD/nR8 [3] => xVqJZ3UtD+ZIchQNsSWhWYZqfuOa/Dj9WZvohqdXOutgecBi6zxLyeG5OIAfy+9NleGz [4] => 6xLfiVWo56heKLXBqXeNbNaQ+LXLDvKm6E6i1uiCeYUmM/tw0ZIkQdruRVqP2xGqzXKh [5] => xvgl8cljKaG5MDPNmU8v/hc0rHFGKAcJi8J20nPeYdfp10djiXfLU1v9OxV/UayEf5l3 [6] => 0yPhGW9shprFd+GvB4dgZ+OLtn/R5mjEW+vYeKIthvfs2Dga2O63icmBRweGEHg8yeyX 0kig== ) [arc_message_signature] => Array ( [0] => i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; [1] => s=arc-20160816; [2] => h=in-reply-to:references:subject:from:date:message-id:auto-submitted [3] => :to:dkim-signature; bh=HVsNyAXsGd1kVtDekkg2HxIra2/JCXrqUZz681BppKw=; [4] => b=hFfcZH0aA/LJbX5isnTOLKGlkUAVzb/qxN0GDBIoeC2eUb0xQDH4RCIOCorS3RP8zk [5] => jzJPOmJtz8Vj8+IwFb5yYbJv9piGVXQzBHjhdJhlSrO+oPm+l1yG0wys1a4wqWbqrWAw [6] => VDFsmEAJF9+9I4bi0Wtng1ta6hi/Mv+9sBEdPt2RQlDmdqOhVDZEqRJLHxcUgIdFPCVZ [7] => 4cU9oQZWu+3V6PU1x7Rdjn11gQFBmWICrO3FTE5Op7wPsMc3vHm1NYFVS8netcE/CQpB [8] => kYj/c/rpTrDhwdxiz6phRGFpE5o81ZIfe2p3/z8bWwZG7ILHuZmH3nDD2Fwxrzt9qFls mDZQ== ) [arc_authentication_results] => Array ( [0] => i=1; mx.google.com; dkim=pass [1] => header.i=@googlemail.com header.s=20161025 header.b=Sz17ewkg; spf=pass [2] => (google.com: best guess record for domain of [3] => postmaster@mail-sor-f69.google.com designates 209.85.220.69 as permitted [4] => sender) smtp.helo=mail-sor-f69.google.com; dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE [5] => sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=googlemail.com ) [return_path] => <> <> [received_spf] => Array ( [0] => pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of [1] => postmaster@mail-sor-f69.google.com designates 209.85.220.69 as permitted [2] => sender) client-ip=209.85.220.69; ) [authentication_results] => Array ( [0] => mx.google.com; dkim=pass header.i=@googlemail.com [1] => header.s=20161025 header.b=Sz17ewkg; spf=pass (google.com: best guess record [2] => for domain of postmaster@mail-sor-f69.google.com designates 209.85.220.69 as [3] => permitted sender) smtp.helo=mail-sor-f69.google.com; dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE [4] => sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=googlemail.com ) [dkim_signature] => Array ( [0] => v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=googlemail.com; [1] => s=20161025; h=to:auto-submitted:message-id:date:from:subject:references [2] => :in-reply-to; bh=HVsNyAXsGd1kVtDekkg2HxIra2/JCXrqUZz681BppKw=; [3] => b=Sz17ewkg50XRKx13ZXL+uhs7X0kxjI7llTlUED6DSysnUo0GeLXgvQwRao3AM5hLUr [4] => r6TCdSIUIwuLOfdl8hmouMadPdH2gB8a0KF2FYDHffWwYNir1hNLBVTyXvo5LPwykMvP [5] => EgqjIC8hNpdG93Dd8Zu0/65iaWGJhBf4Tm3N/f3BRHYV50xkfiov2ahQZwqlvY9wUeco [6] => /VWSoJZ66qUTfyn9nrs9arRV52tmMeoggox9ttUy7Iz1w62al6IrxYiDDyWDdgMOXxEw [7] => qe4nrEPXGSClSFrbAAySQkRT89iwpc3AEfK8tYcF4JOqd5eKbLCloIjFmdkcrI0wT/W4 c85w== ) [x_google_dkim_signature] => Array ( [0] => v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=1e100.net; [1] => s=20161025; [2] => h=x-gm-message-state:to:auto-submitted:message-id:date:from:subject [3] => :references:in-reply-to; bh=HVsNyAXsGd1kVtDekkg2HxIra2/JCXrqUZz681BppKw=; [4] => b=bAyKPMCTjikcjsyEbB2ibqPegW9t9hHkozBFt6PJfqslJwnt1jpBJOlQbXF6lIIsM8 [5] => DWDiaKVQy2sPRLw/TmDFXl1GDhUOrZWAyQ2Q5w4QYscsVMOUVLbuFhlVbl44ymn+Lfzd [6] => wtNni3koNftCRnAcCySkt5mqPhZLgagPMX0/afPKAeW9bKCrCrXKjv4cXXCX4ojD1/e9 [7] => 9M4iC76e1mqy4MOEb8JdYSfXuuQuKh5dHN97kX0H7LisPmMvZxIMlQiI0+2LsEx5eG4k [8] => gBRe2RuKDNgeTjbUGaSP+pyU32PZZIcHzhBNxQe6W9RyrgN0pPevYY4cOP9+xKH4f2Ug ggkw== ) [x_gm_message_state] => AOAM531WciQHOtxqIaSzQO4gea2X9+tWwU/SYEYWxHxzU1sV4LXznlG1 eT9u1p1APRctY02WPSHp9kzxnP82+e2FdOU+JXZ/2g== [x_google_smtp_source] => ABdhPJzX5IFD/kv3qPD1smc2KPY3k5YnHwKkGPrXRCYiqcETxF4d4O5XCd1SAfrlKi6WHdq714K+XraLZOYvXWSjaz7qacYYDv1bfEc= [content_type] => multipart/report [auto_submitted] => auto-replied [x_failed_recipients] => gh528@gmail.com [toaddress] => chamere528@gmail.com [fromaddress] => Mail Delivery Subsystem [reply_toaddress] => Mail Delivery Subsystem [senderaddress] => Mail Delivery Subsystem [boundary] => 00000000000073416e05b73327e3 [report-type] => delivery-status ) [config:protected] => Array ( [delimiter] => / [fetch] => 2 [sequence] => 3 [fetch_body] => 1 [fetch_flags] => 1 [message_key] => list [fetch_order] => asc [dispositions] => Array ( [0] => attachment [1] => inline ) [common_folders] => Array ( [root] => INBOX [junk] => INBOX/Junk [draft] => INBOX/Drafts [sent] => INBOX/Sent [trash] => INBOX/Trash ) [decoder] => Array ( [message] => utf-8 [attachment] => utf-8 ) [open] => Array ( ) ) [fallback_encoding] => UTF-8 ) 1
```

Is there any way to access the 'X-Failed-Recipients' value from this? Or Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webklex/laravel-IMAP had another method getXFailedRecipients() which was not present in the documentation here: https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap.

This solved the problem:

```
$result = $oMessage->getXFailedRecipients();
```

Comment: Hello question, you have made search by UUID, that is to say, that it looks for of id example 7 in ahead?

Comment: @aadesh-dhakal Thank you! You saved me a lot of hours of searching!